# Redshift - String column getting truncated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, parquet

We utilize an AWS Glue crawler to ingest Parquet files stored in Amazon S3. The crawler detects the schema and metadata of the Parquet files and creates an external schema/table in Amazon Redshift. We noticed that the string column is getting truncated in redshift where its retrieving string till 16383 in length. In Athena when we query the Glue table it shows the correct length and whole data. We would like to know why it is truncating the length and what we could do to fix this issue.

We tried changing the for datatype to varchar but its throwing spectrum scan error. I think this is due to source parquet file datatype being string.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a leap on my part but the string length of 16,383 characters is almost exactly 1/4 of the max varchar length for Redshift of 65,535 bytes.  Also Redshift uses multi-byte UTF-8 to encode text which CAN use up to 4 bytes to store 1 character (but rarely does).

I suspect that Glue may be "protecting" you from having errors by truncating (in some way) the data you can see in Redshift.  If you can only see 16K of characters and IF all these characters are 4 bytes in length (nearly impossible), then you won't see strings that overflow Redshift's 64K varchar limit.

Can you provide the DDL of the table and the external table definition?  Is Athena using exactly the same data catalog information as Spectrum? These will help in understanding what might be going on.

I know this isn't an answer but hopefully a good lead on what is happening.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In the Parquet file we receive, one of the columns contains JSONB data. We've been utilizing the "super" datatype for our external table, and it has allowed us to access most of the data for this column successfully. However, we've encountered some columns where the maximum length of the JSONB data reaches around 190K characters.

What datatype would be suitable to handle JSONB data of this length? We're seeking recommendations on the best datatype or approach to efficiently handle and store JSONB data with such large lengths.

Comment: I'm not an expert in Glue and I don't see what Redshift commands are being issued so this may not reflect what you are seeing.  You should have the SERIALIZETOJSON option enabled -  "By specifying SERIALIZETOJSON in the COPY command, you can load any column type in the file that aligns with a SUPER column in the table as SUPER."  If you don't have this would cause you problems. Also, individual values within a SUPER object are limited to the maximum length of the corresponding Amazon Redshift type - A string value loaded to a SUPER field is limited to the maximum VARCHAR length of 65535 bytes.